# lighttpd force close connection

Tags: http, lighttpd, httpresponse

I have a M2M project that sends out the following headers.

```
HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: zh-cn
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
RANGE:bytes=0-1023
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Apache and ISS have `connection : close` in the response headers, regardless of the request to `keep-alive`.  Lighttpd I assume is actually performing correctly as it does keep the connection alive, or does not send a `connection : close`. I actually need it to close the connection for the M2M machine to work. I tried

```
 setenv.add-response-header = ( "connection" => "close" )
```

But this is ignored, anyway to force a connection close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by modifying `server.max-keep-alive-idle`. If you set this to `0`, then the connection will close right after the data is served