# Force connection close lighttpd

Tags: php, http-headers, lighttpd, httpconnection

I need to run code in background for some time, after output is send to client.
But connection blocks and won't close until job is finished.

Looked at :
 [How do I close a connection early?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/how-do-i-close-a-connection-early#141026)
 https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#71172
(and other linked answers)

I ended up with code :

```
    // credit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/how-do-i-close-a-connection-early#141026
    //          and related sources
    // broken on : lighttpd/1.4.53 - php/7.1.3

    $size=ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: $size",1);
    header("Connection: close",1);
    header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");

    // flush all output
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    ob_end_clean();

    // if you're using sessions, this prevents subsequent requests
    // from hanging while the background process executes
    if (session_id()) session_write_close();

    ... some code for 10 seconds here
```

I tried both :
        server.max-keep-alive-idle=0
        server.max-keep-alive-requests = 0
Taken from :
        [lighttpd force close connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453661/lighttpd-force-close-connection)
        https://serverfault.com/questions/283377/force-connection-close-lighttpd
(put inside /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf)

My setup :
        lighttpd/1.4.53
        php/7.1.3
        Firefox 68.6.0esr (32-bit)
        Raspberry Pi 4
        Raspbian
        uname -a : Linux raspberrypi 4.19.97-v7l+ #1294 SMP Thu Jan 30 13:21:14 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux

Enabled lighttpd modules :
        10-accesslog.conf
        10-fastcgi.conf
        10-rewrite.conf
        15-fastcgi-php.conf
        90-javascript-alias.conf

**Purpose :**
 It's simple MUD game code.
 It is there to refresh AIs **once per second**.
 It is periodicaly started by player's presence in game like this :
 
 1] Script will process player's command,
    then connection should be closed to not bother player's browser
 2] check lock-file and if it's free - lock it
 3] then stay in background for 10 updates
    After that, file is unlocked,
    so another player's command can start another bg job

Comment: could you be more detailed about what you're trying to accomplish by displaying more of your code?  What is executing this code?

Comment: @Nibb sure .. I isolated functional example here : https://pastebin.com/WBTDKVVC

Comment: @Nibb .. sorry, I now realized, that my question was really not well stated ... added 'purpose' at and of question

Answer (score 0):

If *your code* needs to do processing after it has sent a CGI response, then *your code* needs to do so in a separate execution context, since the CGI has done its job when it sends the CGI response, and lighttpd will then send a SIGTERM signal to your script.

One way to run code after sending a CGI response is to run the code in the background after sending a CGI response.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setsid.php

Another way is for your CGI to put a job into a job queue and have a standalone daemon, separate from the CGI, process the queue, e.g. using a redis server.

Comment: It is meant to be run on server without such level of control (payed hosting), so I came up with this self-started background thingy .. I forgot to mention it, sorry